# Why use StyleProp<ViewStyle> over ViewStyle?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-props

I am looking at some React Native Typescript code and seeing components taking in style props.
These are typed as `StyleProp<ViewStyle>`. That type causes me problems though, like not being able to spread the prop (I might want to spread to override `backgroundColor` for instance).

```
interface Props {
   aStyleProp: StyleProp<ViewStyle>
}
```

So I just typed `aStyleProp` as `ViewStyle`.

Am I losing something important by not using `StyleProp`?

[Code trying to spread prop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhTvF.png)

Looking through the type definition for `StyleProp` (imported from 'react-native') I don't feel wiser from the `RegisteredStyle<T>` and `RecursiveArray` which are its possible types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StyleProp<ViewStyle>` accepts a wider range of types than `ViewStyle`.

The definition of `StyleProp<T>`:

```
export type StyleProp<T> =
  | T
  | RegisteredStyle<T>
  | RecursiveArray<T | RegisteredStyle<T> | Falsy>
  | Falsy;
```

So when it comes to `StyleProp<ViewStyle>` it accepts not only `ViewStyle` type, but also an array of `ViewStyle`s, and a `Falsy` type, which translates to `false || null || undefined`.

This means that for example this is valid for `StyleProp<ViewStyle>` but not valid for `ViewStyle`:

- `style={[styles.style1, styles.style2]}` - array of styles
- `style={undefined}` - any `Falsy` value